# jQuery search for a specific element in a group of selectors, if not found, add it

Tags: jquery, loops

I need to search class "a2" in a group of "container" divs. If it's found, do nothing; if it's missing, add it.

Original code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="a1">
    <span class="Label">Status:</span>
    <span class="Text">Active</span>
  </div>
  <div class="a2">
    <span class="Label">Description:</span>
    <span class="Text">2</span>
  </div>   
</div>

</br>
</br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a1">
    <span class="Label">Status:</span>
    <span class="Text">Active</span>
  </div>
</div>

</br>
</br>

<div class="container">
  <div class="a1">
    <span class="Label">Status:</span>
    <span class="Text">Active</span>
  </div>  
</div>
```

Here is my script:

```
$('div.container').each(function(){
   if($(this).children('.a2').length == 0){  
      $('<div class="a2"><span class="Label">Description:</span><span  class="Text">0</span></div>').insertAfter('div.a1');    
      return false; 
   }      
});
```

see [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/g9G85/78/) here.

The problem is the script inserted the "a2" div in the first "container" which is not needed. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.insertAfter('div.a1');
```

inserts the element after each `div.a1` element. What you want is appending it to the current `div.container`:

```
.appendTo(this);
```

Also, don't `return false`. It will stop the whole loop. The `if` already guards whether or not to add.

Comment: Thanks so much for the explanation, I understand it much better now.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('div.container').filter(function(){
     return $('.a2', this).length === 0;
}).append('<div class="a2"><span class="Label">Description:</span><span class="Text">0</span></div>');
```

or:

```
$('div.container').not(":has('div.a2')")
                  .append('<div class="a2"><span class="Label">Description:</span><span class="Text">0</span></div>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xGACz/

Comment: One could also use `:not(:has(.a2))`.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes, I usually use `filter` method for filtering elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `not` method and the `:has` selector to filter the containers so that you only have those without an `a2` element:

```
$('div.container').not(':has(> .a2)').append(
  $('<div class="a2"><span class="Label">Description:</span><span  class="Text">0</span></div>')
);
```